# Is it a must for an OSGi bundle to have an activator class?

Tags: jsp, web-applications, osgi, osgi-bundle, modularization

I have an osgi bundle, which includes only a .jsp file. Shall I create an activator class for it? If yes, what should it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An OSGI bundle does not need an activator